# Does "started a start-up company" contain redundancy?

Tags: expressions, colloquialisms, phrase-usage, redundancy

I see the phrase "started a start-up company" more and more these days, and feel that it is redundant, and the speaker is ignorant or using stock phrases without thinking. Any company we start would always be a start-up, right ?

Would "started a company" mean the exactly same ? I mean, it is not like we can start a well-established decade-old company, right ?

Comment: Use "founded" instead of "started" there.

Comment: Well , even "founded a start-up company" is redundant , while "founded a company" is good enough.

Comment: "start-up" just means "new".

Comment: Again, we can not start an "old" company ; So , "we started a new company" is still redundant.

Comment: As WS2 has already mentioned, **[start-up company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_company)** (or just "start-up" or "startup") has a particular meaning, so I don't see the obvious redundancy seen by others.  Maybe if you just went with "start-up" or "startup" (without "company") all the suggestions made so far would sound better (maybe even the original "started").

Comment: @PapaPoule , the  wiki starts with ". . . perspective in this article may not represent a worldwide view of the subject . . ." , while WordWeb shows "start-up" == "A new business". I will be going with **"initiated or founded or established or launched a start-up"**.

Comment: Note that all implicit semi-redundancies do not need to be resolved. There is nothing inherently wrong with starting a start-up, shooting a shot, or drinking a drink.

Comment: Proof-reading is off topic for this list. "Acceptable" is primarily opinion-based. Acceptable to whom, for what purpose?

Comment: Changed the question : removed "acceptable" ; now asking for a factual answer.

Comment: @Robusto Exactly. Live a happy life, Dream a sweet dream will all be redundant.

Comment: There's a MOOC from Stanford named "How to start a startup".

Comment: I liked your question and the options you decided to go with. +1 It even generated the following possibility for a future question: "**Does 'investing in [a mature start-up](https://www.redi.com/blog/redi-grows-into-mature-startup)**' contain an oxymoron?"

Comment: @PapaPoule , good one !!

Answer (score 4):

I hear what people say, but ***start-up company*** has a particular meaning, that is a little more than simply a company which gets started.

For that reason I think you should retain *start-up company*.

But you could perhaps say ***He/She began/initiated a start-up company*** or ***...was responsible for a start-up company***.

However the latter does not necessarily mean they were there at the very beginning.

Comment: As per WordWeb , "start-up" == "A new business" , while https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_company shows many (non-standard) Definitions of start-up. **I think you have a point about particular meanings, +1** , but many people (in general) do not know about those particular meanings, and use "start-up" as a stock phrase to mean "new", in which case it is redundant. When I have to use such a phrase, I will use your advice about **"initiated" or "founded"** (courtesy of @Robusto) and atleast avoid the glaring redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

> Any company we start would always be a start-up, right? Would "started a company" mean the exactly same?

Not necessarily. There's quite a number of definitions:

> start-up: a new small company or business, **especially one whose work involves computers or the Internet** (Longman)

Wikipedia has [an insightful section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_company#Definition) about this very topic. Here are some definitions:

> A company, a partnership or temporary organization **designed to
>   search for a repeatable and scalable business model**.

According to this definition, if you start a restaurant (where the business model is well-known, so no need to search for it), you are not founding a start-up.

Another definition:

> A startup is a company designed to grow fast. **Being newly founded does
>   not in itself make a company a startup.** Nor is it necessary for a
>   startup to work on technology, or take venture funding, or have some
>   sort of "exit". **The only essential thing is growth.**

A recently started small "mom-and-pop" store that has no plans to conquer the world would probably not fit this definition.

There are more definitions, and not every new company would be a start-up according to all (and, I think, most) of them.

**So when people say that someone started a start-up, they most likely mean a new, ambitious, trailblazing (possibly, tech) company that's trying to disrupt the market and grow super fast.**

Edit: It's been suggested by others that "started a start-up" is somewhat tautological, and I tend to agree. At least in writing, I'd prefer "He founded a start-up" or similar.

Comment: +1 , but [[ http://www.forbes.com/sites/natalierobehmed/2013/12/16/what-is-a-startup/ : “startup” has been bandied around with increasing frequency . . . .Those who sip the startup Kool-Aid define it as a culture and mentality of innovating on existing ideas to solve critical pain points . . . “Startup is a state of mind,” . . . According to Merriam-Webster, start-up means “a fledgling business enterprise.” . . . **Therein lies the rub – to be a startup, you must have set up shop recently.** ]] Beyond all these non-standard (non-consistent) Definitions , **start-up means new** , to most folks.

Comment: I agree in that being recently founded is *essential*, but not *sufficient* for many definitions of the word "start-up". But yeah, therein lies the rub. No argument there.

Answer (score 0):

very good detailed breakdown @A.P., I also hear much usage of "start-up/startup" in reference to a phase of a company (i.e. Our company is in startup mode)... it seems more connected to a period in a company's history, rather than a "type" of company.

But yes, @Prem, I believe "I founded a company" is the correct way of phrasing the idea without redundancy..

Comment: I think you were not able to comment on the answer by @AP because of shortage of reputation points , so +1 from me , for the insight about "history" rather than "type".